# iOS/Xcode: Creating Photo Filters

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, filter

I am currently exploring ways to create a handful of photo filters for my client. Has anyone else ever worked on creating and implementing filters in Xcode before? How did you go about it and are there any best practices?

What did you use to create the filters? Did you manipulate photos directly through Xcode or did you use Photoshop or similar to begin with?

Alternatively, is there a good set of out-of-the-box filters one could use as a base?

Curious to hear your process.

Comment: If Apple software is the only platform You're asking for read what Quartz Composer is.

Comment: Really depends on your use case -- which from the title I'd assume that these filters run on the iPhone / iOS device, right?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of choices. Apple offers a large number of CI (Core Image) filters that will apply various types of transformations to your image(s). (some filters apply changes to a single image - some blend 2 images, and some filters generate images like patterns and barcodes that don't use any starting image.)

I wrote a demo project (in Objective-C) that shows how to interrogate the system for the list of available filters and apply them to images. You can read about it in this blog post: http://wareto.com/core-image-filter-demo.

**EDIT:

Contrary to what I said in my original post, apparently Apple added support for custom CI Filters in iOS 8. I haven't used that feature yet, but this greatly expands your options here.

There is also a third party library written by Brad Larson called [**GPUImage**](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) that builds custom filters based on OpenGL shaders.

It's also possible to build your own engine based on OpenGL or other frameworks. I wrote my company's (**free**!) app, [**FaceDancer**](http://www.tinyurl.com/facedancer), using Core Image face detection and OpenGL texture mapping.

Comment: Actually you can create custom CI filters since iOS 8! There is a great WWDC 2014 video about it: Developing Core Image Filters for iOS. See also CIColorKernel. But that said, I imagine the existing CI filters are sufficient for photo apps.

Comment: Cool. I need to explore custom CI filters then.